# Can I use dialogs and DialogResult on a UserControl with WPF?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, dialog, dialogresult

I've a UserControl and I need to get input from a dialog. However, when I try to do this:

```
        AddPassword addPassword = new AddPassword();

        if(addPassword.ShowDialog() == == DialogResult.GetValueOrDefault())
        {
            if (addPassword.sTitle != ""
                && addPassword.sUser != ""
                && addPassword.sPass != "")
            {
                LogIn login = new LogIn(addPassword.sTitle, addPassword.sUser, addPassword.sPass);
                LogIns.Add(login);

                lstbxLogins.Items.Add(login.GetTitle());
            }
        }
```

It doesn't find the DialogResult.

Can I actually do this?

Thanks

Comment: If you're going to rank down a new user at least have the courtesy to say why. +1

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't find the DialogResult"? You cannot compile this or you don't get expected result from "addPassword.ShowDialog()"?

Comment: Doesn't compile when I use DialogResult.GetValueOrDefault().
Now, if I just do this if-statement if(addPassword.ShowDialog()), the values I get back from the window are null.

Answer (score 1):

Method `ShowDialog` returns `bool?`, so you should check the result like this:

```
if(addPassword.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: If I use that, I get an exception, InvalidOperationException:

Cannot set Visibility or call Show, ShowDialog, or WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle after a Window has closed.

Comment: @Homero - This means that you are calling ShowDialog() after the window is closed (are you calling it multiple times on the same instance of the window?). But I don't see it in the code you provided, so the problem is probably with something else.